# Creating a combination to solve the following question combinatorically

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, combinations

A student has to take twelve hours of classes a week. Due to her extracurricular activities,
she must take at least three hours of classes on Monday, at least two on Thursday, and at
least one on Friday.

- In how many ways can she do this?
- In how many ways can she do this if there is only one class on Tuesday that she may
  take?

I was thinking of solving both parts of this problem using a composition following the theorem:

$\forall$ positive integers n and k, the number of weak compositions of n into k parts is

$\binom{n+k-1}{k-1} = \binom{n+k-1}{n}$

- Assuming there are 5 days to learn and we need to disperse the last 6 hours we plug this in to get the first question:

$\binom{5+6-1}{6-1}$ = $\frac{10!}{5!5!}$

- Now using the same assumptions and letting there be one class on Tuesday we now have a total of 4 useable days with 5 hours to disperse, giving us:

$\binom{4+5-1}{5-1}$ = $\frac{8!}{4!4!}$

Does this seem like a good way to do it, or is there a better way to solve is combinatorically? Also is it safe to assume that we should only use 5 days to take classes instead of 7 days?

Thank you for any answers/comments!

Comment: There are some assumptions you need to make here. For example, that on any day, you can’t take fractional hours of classes, and the only days you can take classes are Monday through Friday.

Comment: For the second problem, it is not required that she take a class on Tuesday.  You also have to consider the case where she does not take a class on Tuesday.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for your reply! Im not sure I really established the M-F part but that is why I used 5 instead of 7. I don't think this should include fractional parts of classes but how would I ensure that?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you for reply! So the second part has half the question done where it is if she takes the class on Tuesday, so now I would have to add in another combination where it stays 4 for the number of days possible but the hours(denoted as 5 in part 2) now increase to 6?

Comment: Are we assuming that as many as $9$ hours are possible on a single day?  If so, this is a stars-and-bars problem with (in part b) the constraint that $x_2 \leq 1$.

Comment: @RobertShore Thanks for your reply! The thing I am worried about is the problem lists no constraints. That's why I'm not even sure if I should even limit the days from 7 to 5.

Comment: Your calculation is wrong because $n=6$, not $5$.  Your technique appears correct, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that it's possible to take $9$ hours of class in a single day and that fractional hours are not possible.

For the first question, you want to solve $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=6$.  The technique of stars and bars tells us that there are $\binom{10}{4}=210$ solutions in non-negative integers to this equation.

For the second question, you want to add the constraint that $x_2 \leq 1$.  Solve this by finding the number of solutions for which $x_2 \gt 1:  x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=4$  There are $\binom 84$ such solutions so there are $\binom {10}{4}-\binom 84 =140$ solutions for which $x_2 \leq 1$.

Comment: I definitely agree on using stars and bars, but why choose 4 in both problems? Shouldn't we let the $k-1 = 6-1$ where the 6 is the number of hours remaining? And for the second part should we do options she has if she uses the one hour on Tuesday + if she doesn't use Tuesday?

Comment: @MSquared I don't have the formula memorized.  I solve stars-and-bars problems visually, using the $+$ signs as the bars.  There are $4$ of them between the $5$ variables.  You have miscalculated because $n=6, k=5$.

Comment: Sorry I am new to stars and bars but why is $n=6$ and $k=5$ in this case? If we let the number of days you could take classes be 7 instead of 5 would it change to $n=7$ and $k=6$?

Comment: @MSquared In the first part of the problem, $n$ represents the number of hours per week of class.  So, the original problem is $y_1 + \cdots + y_5 = 12$, where each of the variables must be a non-negative integer.  Then, given the constraints of the problem, you can set $x_1 = y_1 - 3, ~x_2 = y_2, x_3 = y_3, x_4 = y_4 - 2, x_5 = y_5 - 1$.  This translates into $x_1 + \cdots + x_5 = 6$.  Also, the number of variables is (**somewhat arbitrarily**) assumed to be $5$ rather than $(7)$ (hence $k = 5$), because university classes are normally not scheduled on Saturday or Sunday.  ...see next comment

Comment: @MSquared Re setting $(k = 5)$, rather than $(k = 7)$, in the previous comment, certainly the presumption is not iron-clad.  However, the presumption is *circumstantially suggested* by the problem's added constraints that focus on class hours on Monday, Thursday, and Friday.  Note that in the problem constraints, no suggestion/mention was made of the (in real life) *somewhat* non-standard scheduling of classes on Saturday or Sunday.

Comment: @MSquared $n$ is the number of hours, not the number of days.  The number of days is $k$.  Using your vocabulary, you're composing $6$ hours across $5$ days.